# Create Swift code from Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, git, storyboard

I would like track changes of the GUI development in GIT.
On the other hand I like to use the storyboard to develop GUIs.

Is there a way to generate Swift code from the Storyboards XIB file, that instantiates and initialises the GUI objects from code.

If that´s not possible, is there another way to reach my goal - tracking changes in GIT and using the storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard files are just a specialized type of XML file, like SOAP or XSL. Control-click on one and open it in your favorite text editor and you'll see for yourself.

Thus, tracking changes to a storyboard file (through Git or elsewhere) is the same as any other file, except you need to use something other than Xcode.

As for converting storyboard XML to Swift - there are no utilities out there for that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Git tracking, but for general-purpose UI refactoring, from Xib or Storyboard files to Swift source code, the [tool is exists](https://microcodingapps.com/products/decode.html) (Disclaimer: I'm the author of it).

It generates view properties (e.g. font, backgroundColor, etc), layout constraints and trait collection variations. Works with Xib or Storyboard files designed for iOS, tvOS or macOS platforms.